# AREA Field in ARM Assembly

Tags: arm, keil

Hi I'm using the Keil uVision compiler for ARM assembly. I'm just starting out learning this and I have the following code in my program.

```
AREA PROGRAM, CODE, READONLY
EXPORT SYSTEMINIT
EXPORT __MAIN
SYSTEMINIT
__MAIN
    MOV R1, #0X25
    MOV R2, #0X23
    END
```

When I build the target it says

test.s(1): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode PROGRAM, , expecting opcode or Macro

I'm not sure why that is. The code above s the code I was given to run as a sample to make sure its working. Shouldn't I be able to put anything in for AREA? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error message is informative, if a little hard to decipher: [anything that starts in the first column is considered to be a label](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/CEGHJDFB.html), so the assembler sees a label named "AREA", then tries to interpret "PROGRAM," as a mnemonic, macro, or directive, which obviously fails since it isn't.

In short, directives need to be indented, just like instructions; this assembles just fine:

```
    AREA PROGRAM, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT SYSTEMINIT
    EXPORT __MAIN
SYSTEMINIT
__MAIN
    MOV R1, #0X25
    MOV R2, #0X23
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

The AREA directive instructs the assembler to assemble a new code or data section. Sections are independent, named, indivisible chunks of code or data that are manipulated by the linker.
**Syntax**

```
AREA sectionname{,attr}{,attr}...
```

where:

*sectionname* s the name to give to the section. You can choose any name for your sections.

So check you have the same name in both places: right after the *AREA* directive and somewhere in your code.

Further reading about directives you can find [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Chedcbai.html).